# ANR on receive "android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON"

Tags: android-anr-dialog

we receive following ANR log on Google Play Console.

```
#00 pc 0000000000068e94 /system/lib64/libc.so (__ioctl+4)
#01 pc 0000000000024428 /system/lib64/libc.so (ioctl+132)
#02 pc 00000000000619ec /system/lib64/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::talkWithDriver(bool)+256)
#03 pc 0000000000062784 /system/lib64/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::waitForResponse(android::Parcel*, int*)+340)
#04 pc 00000000000624a4 /system/lib64/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::transact(int, unsigned int, android::Parcel const&, android::Parcel*, unsigned int)+216)
#05 pc 0000000000056df0 /system/lib64/libbinder.so (android::BpBinder::transact(unsigned int, android::Parcel const&, android::Parcel*, unsigned int)+72)
#06 pc 0000000000120afc /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (???)
#07 pc 0000000000953bf4 /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (Java_android_os_BinderProxy_transactNative__ILandroid_os_Parcel_2Landroid_os_Parcel_2I+196)
at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative (BinderProxy.java)
at android.os.BinderProxy.transact (BinderProxy.java:748)
at android.hardware.display.IDisplayManager$Stub$Proxy.isHighSpeedDisplayApp (IDisplayManager.java:602)
at android.hardware.display.DisplayManagerGlobal.isHighSpeedDisplayApp (DisplayManagerGlobal.java:555)
at android.view.Display.getRefreshRate (Display.java:811)
- locked <0x014e4025> (a android.view.Display)
at Lk3.h (Lk3.java:21)
at Jk3.onDisplayChanged (Jk3.java:7)
at android.hardware.display.DisplayManagerGlobal$DisplayListenerDelegate.handleMessage (DisplayManagerGlobal.java:482)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:105)
at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6627)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (Zygote.java:240)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

it seems like occured on「android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON」received when broadcast intent kicked on sleep device off.
and this process looks like in AndroidSDK layer.
in addition, log "Jk3.onDisplayChanged (Jk3.java:7)" is from Chrome process.
I don't know how we should fix these 2 layer's problem.

I want know following to solve this problem.

1. how we get "Jk3.onDisplayChanged (Jk3.java:7)" on operation with Android device ?
2. how we can solve this "Jk3.onDisplayChanged (Jk3.java:7)" problem ?

thx.